# Semi-survival copula

Tags: probability, copula

I'm currently doing some reading on copula function. For a bivariate cdf, by Sklar's theorem, there exists a copula function,C, such that

$P(U<u,V<v) = C(u, v)$.

As written by Nelsen (2006), A survival copula is given by

$P(U>u,V>v) = 1-u-v+C(u,v)$.

From here, implying 1-u=u* and 1-v=v*
the left hand side can be simplified as

$P(U>u,V>v)=Ĉ(u^*,v^*)=u^*+v^*-1+C(1-u^*,1-v^*)$.

Here, the link between ordinary copula (C without hat) and survival copula (C with hat) is understandable. However, I have read a recent journal regarding semi-survival copula which stated that for a semi-survival copula, it is written as

$P(U<u,V>v) = Ĉ(u,v^*) = C(u,1-v)$.

I tried to derive the semi-survival using the same concept as survival copula but get a different equation from above. The derivation goes as follows:

$Ĉ(u,1-v) = 1-(1-u+C(u,v))$

$Ĉ(u,1-v) = u-C(u,v)$

Let 1-v=v*

This implies
$Ĉ(u,v^*) = u-C(u,1-v^*)$.

I got an extra u and the C(u,1-v*) has negative sign. Which part did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Relations like that can be derived in a straightforward manner without looking into any literature from
  $$\tag{1}
  \mathbb P(U<u,V<v)=C(u,v)\,,
  $$
  and
  \begin{align}
  1&=\underbrace{\mathbb P(U<u,V<v)}_{C(u,v)}+\mathbb P(U\ge u,V<v)+\mathbb P(U<u,V\ge v)\nonumber\\
  &\quad+\mathbb P(U\ge u,V\ge v)\,.\tag{2}
  \end{align}
  The last term is what seems to be called survival copula. The middle terms are
  \begin{align}\tag{3}
  \mathbb P(U\ge u,V<v)&=\mathbb P(V<v)-\mathbb P(U<u,V<v)=C(+\infty,v)-C(u,v)\,,\\
  \tag{4}
  \mathbb P(U<u,V\ge v)&=\mathbb P(U<u)-\mathbb P(U<u,V<v)=C(v,+\infty)-C(u,v)\,.
  \end{align}
- For
  $$\tag{5}
  \mathbb P(U<u,V\ge v)=C(u,1-v)
  $$
  to hold we must have
  $$\tag{6}
  \mathbb P(U<u,V\ge v)=\mathbb P(U<u,V<1-v)\,.
  $$
  In particular,
  $$\tag{7}
  \mathbb P(V\ge v)=1-\mathbb P(V<v)=\mathbb P(V<1-v)\,.
  $$
  Taking the derivative w.r.t. $v$ shows that the density of $V$ must satisfy
  $$\tag{8}
  p(v)=p(1-v)\,.
  $$
  This means that $p$ must be symmetric around $\frac{1}{2}\,.$
  Obviously,  not every PDF satisfies this relationship. Two prime examples of such a density are that of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ or the
  standard normal PDF with mean $\frac{1}{2}\,:$
  $$
  p(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\Big(-\frac{(v-1/2)^2}{2}\Big)\,.
  $$

Comment: This is well explained! Thus, if the density is not symmetric, does this means that we can only use equation (3) and (4) to find P(U≥u,V<v) & P(U<u,V≥v) respectively?

Comment: Obviously. $\phantom{.}$